# How to run ArrayList.add() immediately?

Tags: java, arraylist

```
 ArrayList<Student> list = new ArrayList<>(); 
   /*Student just have (ID,name,semester and ArrayList<String> course */

 int ID;
 String name, semester;
 ArrayList<String> course = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then I add some student to list

```
        ID= 123;
        name = "Hoang Van Lam";
        semester = "Spring2020";
        course.add("JAVA");
        course.add("C#");
        course.add("PYTHON");
        list.add(new Student(ID,name,semester,course));
        course.clear();
```

After that, I want to add more students, I try to use `course.clear();` to reuse `cousre`.
Then I realized that `course.clear` had run before `list.add ()` had taken it.So How can i improve this problem? Thanks all

Comment: Where not just use course = new ArrayList<String>()?

Comment: I use ArrayList<String> course to store many course name of student. Here is student class: ` private int ID;
    private String name;
    private String semester;
    private ArrayList<String> course;

    public Student() {
    }

    public Student(int ID, String name, String semester, ArrayList<String> course) {
        this.ID = ID;
        this.name = name;
        this.semester = semester;
        this.course = course;
    }`

Comment: If you reuse the same list instance for `course`, it doesn't matter whether that was done before or after `list.add()`, all students will have the same list of courses in the end (the one you add last)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass an Object to the constructore you pass its "reference" so when you call `course.clear()` you simply clear it and now the object is empty anywhere! If you want to have a new list you can create one and use `course` to refer to it again :

```
ID= 123;
name = "Hoang Van Lam";
semester = "Spring2020";
course.add("JAVA");
course.add("C#");
course.add("PYTHON");
list.add(new Student(ID,name,semester,course));
course= new ArrayList<>();
```